# React - Map content inside a div

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Good Morning! Why does my map content stay outside the "blog--div" div?
It's getting loose on Body and I do not know why. Help-me, please!

I try to put a border around the contents of the "blog--div" but the content becomes loose, making it impossible to apply styles.

```
imports[...]


class Blog extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            post: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true })
        fetch(`${API}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    post: [res],
                    isLoading: false,
                })
            })
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoading } = this.state
        if (isLoading) {
            return <Loading />
        }
        return (
            <div className="blog">
                <p className="blog__title">Blog</p>
                {this.renderBlog()}

            </div>
        )
    }


    renderBlog() {
        const page = this.state.post.map((post, key) => {
            return (
                <div className="blog--div" key={key}>

                    <div className="blog__post">
                        <div className="blog__post--title">
                            <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={post[0].link}>{post[0].title.rendered.replace('Visit.Rio', 'Projeto 1')}</a></p>
                        </div>

                        <div className="blog__post--description">
                            <p>{post[0].excerpt.rendered.replace('Visit.Rio', 'Projeto 1')}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })
        return page
    }
}

export default Blog
```

Comment: Please add css of Blog component. Please check that some other component does not define css for class 'blog' and its child classes

Comment: Hello, @SashaKos! The problem is that in the chrome console (inspect) t is possible to see that the content is not inside any div, but rather, loose in the body.

Comment: Did you try to remove 'map' and leave static divs? Did you see the same?